# Why source spoofed packets cant be transmitted over internet?

Tags: sockets

I use raw socket to spoof source IP packets but I can't receive spoofed packets in target.

If my ip is: `44.44.44.44`

I can't receive packets with source IP: `44.44.44.45`.

There is two computer (A and B)
i spoof source ip of packets and send them to B
in B i cant see the source spoofed packets...

Comment: -1 Your question is more vague than the average Facebook picture taken with a mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not.  The receiver uses the source IP field to determine who to send responses to.  So if you spoof the field in packets you send, then the responses won't get sent to you.

Comment: i think you dont understand my question

There is two computer (A and B)
i spoof source ip of packets and send them to B
in B i cant see the source spoofed packets...

Comment: @VictorXV: Ok.  In that case, please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: There is two computer (A and B) i spoof source ip of packets and send them to B in B i cant see the source spoofed packets...